# How should I store SQL queries in my API server?

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I'm making an API server that require SQL queries that has something like 20-40 lines.

I want it to be a simple server so I'm using NodeJS, express, body-parser and a database connector.

In other environments, I understand that you either use final constants or import SQL files but I don't know what's the best method in Node.

I think reading in individual SQL file for every query will be slow and since JavaScript does not support multiline string, saving them in a json object would seem tedious.

(I know ES6/Babel exists but it seems like an overkill for just one functionality).

So the question is what's the best and the most common way to store SQL queries in the context of node/express?

Answer (score 0):

20-40 lines seems like a lot... Have you considered making those queries [views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) or [stored procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)?

The other thing is that if you are using at least NodeJS 4.6.1 you can use template literals out of the box

Comment: Can you add an example on how template literals would help?

Comment: That's **only** in the case that OP still prefers to store the queries as a multi-line string in JS.